# Error when rendering React Portal with Storyshots

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, storybook, storyshots

I'm trying to render a modal using a portal, it works fine in my application as well as in Storybook, but as soon as it is added to Storyshots I run into problems.

The first issue was to mock ReactDOM's createPortal API.  I did it like:

`ReactDOM.createPortal = element => element;`

If this is not added, I get the following error:

> Error: Uncaught [TypeError: parentInstance.children.indexOf is not a function]

I found this solution [React Portal Error](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11565#issuecomment-368877149).

This solves this issue, but then when the component uses the portal it fails when trying to append the child.  It doesn't find the 'modal-root' component, and thus can't append the element.  I'm not sure how to get past this.

My portal looks pretty much the same as the example on the React website:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createPortal } from 'react-dom';
import { node } from 'prop-types';

class Portal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.el = document.createElement('div');
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // !!!!!!!fails here !!!!!!!!!
    document.getElementById('modal-root').appendChild(this.el);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.getElementById('modal-root').removeChild(this.el);
  }

  render() {
    return createPortal(this.props.children, this.el);
  }
}
```

It now fails with this error:

> Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null]

Position indicated in the code snippet above.

Comment: Just in case, maybe it is a silly comment but just to be sure: in your markup(html) do you have a element with id = 'modal-root'?

Comment: Did you got the answer for this? It will be great to update and close this question

Answer (score 6):

You can do 2 different things:

In `.storybook` add a new DOM element:

```
let modalRoot = document.createElement("div")
modalRoot.setAttribute("id", "modal-root")
document.querySelector("body")!.appendChild(modalRoot)
```

Also another thing you can do is to mock document, since the problem is that you are trying to find a dom element that does no exist.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11565#issuecomment-368877149) you can install [rc-util](https://github.com/react-component/util) and add the following to either the top of your test or (if you want it global) inside your jest.setup.js (or package.json jest section if that is what you use).

```js
jest.mock('rc-util/lib/Portal')
```

PS. If you using [CRA](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) your jest setup file is in `src/setupTests.js`

Answer (score 1):

Another approach. Place the following in your jest setup file:

```js
jest.mock('react-dom', () => {
  const original = jest.requireActual('react-dom');
  return {
    ...original,
    createPortal: node => node,
  };
});
```